# Sql Server Full Text Search not return exact searching word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I tried search word which is "alevi" on fulltext index column .

But it returns rows which include "alevi" and addition "alev" which is without suffix "alev".(alev-i in turkish lang.)

> `SELECT  * FROM MYTABLE  where (CONTAINS(MYCOLUMN,'alevi'))`

i want to only return rows which include "alevi".

i tried freetext,N'alevi','"alevi"'
but it still return "alev"

i dont want to return with/without suffix /plural suffix.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: may be this works SELECT * FROM MYTABLE where (CONTAINS(MYCOLUMN,'"alevi*"'))

Comment: thanks but it doesnt work. it still returns "alev"...

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the stemming functionality of Full Text search, applied to your language. You can disable it by specifying a neutral language:

SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE FREETEXT(MYCOLUMN, 'alevi', LANGUAGE 0x0)

Comment: Yes,i guess about language. but i dont know how to disable.
Thanks a lot,it worked!

Comment: There is a another problem :)
"ı" letter not return when i use tihs method. for example searching "kadın" returns no row. but there are about 1000 row which include "kadın".